# MSSQLSERVER agent from Services.msc

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent

Quick question from a conversation with a colleague, I would always restart things like MSSQLSERVER agent from SSCM, however a colleague asking what the difference would be starting restarting the service from services.msc.

It never occured to me if there would be any impact restarting the service from here as opposed to Sql Server Configuration Manager, is it just a best practise thing? Also it is SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2. Any thoughts on if there any any adverse effects starting/restarting from services.msc?

Thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely a best practice.  Restarting through Windows services will work but may lead to a slippery slope.  Using SSCM out of habit helps avoid the temptation to make changes to the services through Windows Services where registry settings may get out of sync.